# refer to a component's name

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, global-variables

Is there a way to get the name off of an apex:component?

For example:

```
<apex:component>
   ...
   The name of this component is {!$Component.Name}    
</apex:component>
```

Or something like that?

Comment: What do you need that for? have you tried {!$component.this} ??

Answer (score 1):

Put an Id attribute on the component. Then you can use that to get the DOM ID via the [`$Component`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_component.htm) global variable.

```
<apex:component id="myComponentId">
   The name of this component is {!$Component.myComponentId}    
</apex:component>
```

See also:

- Online docs: [Best Practices for Accessing Component IDs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm)

Comment: You should mention that you must also name all intermediate ids as well: `{!$Component.myForm.myPageBlock.mySection.myField}`